# IE 11 gets into a loop after aborting GET request

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-11

I've a usecase where an Ajax (GET) call results a response with a URL to goto, and JavaScript after receiving this response, tries to go to this URL by setting 'window.location' to this URL.
In one case URL in the response is the same as the URL of Ajax call, except one less request parameter.

In this perticular case, IE11 aborts the request (which is result of window.location = myresponUrl), and makes the Ajax call again; and this gets into a infinate loop.

And points what is causing it and how to fix it?

it is something like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: './some-url?param1=a&param2=b',
   success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
    var redirectUrl = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Ajax-Location');
    if (redirectUrl) {
       // redirectUrl has value './some-url?param1=a'
       // below statements results a GET and is aborted immediately by IE11, 
       // and request is made to ./some-url?param1=a&param2=b
       window.location = redirectUrl;
    }
    // other processing
   }
});
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code if you want us to help you fix it.

Comment: Does your mention of IE11 doing this mean that you've tried other versions of IE and other browsers and they *don't* do this? What calls the code you've shown? (Is it from an event listener for an event that might naturally refresh the page, e.g., a form submit handler?)

Comment: Didn't check on other IE versions, but tried FF, Chrome - they work fine.
A timer (set using setInterval) results the first Ajax GET call.

Comment: After doing bit more investigation into it, I see the this happens when the application is accessed with 'Internet zone', works fine when accessed with 'Intranet zone'. Eg: Accessing with localhost its treated as intranet zone, accessing with IP forces it to be treated as Internet zone.
Still trying to find root cause though :(